# VBA/ADO: reading mixed data types from a .csv datasource

Tags: sql, vba, csv, ado

I'm having a problem reading in mixed datatypes from a .csv datasource: Strings are returned as Null's when I have a column with mixed String/Numeric values. I have set IMEX=1 and changed the Registry entry TypeGuessRows from 8 to 0 (but even if I have mixed datatypes within the first 8 rows, strings are still coming through as Null). Also ImportMixedTypes=Text in the registry.

What am I missing?? Any ideas much appreciated.

Here's my connection string:

```
ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
    & "Data Source=" & Folder & ";" _
    & "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited;IMEX=1';" _
    & "Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Comment: Have you read this (bottom part about postcodes and adding a resgistry key: ImportMixedTypes = Text): http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196

Answer (score 1):

Here is another code sample **that does not use ADO**, similar to what Fink posted, with a little more flexibility and error handling. Performance is not too bad (reads and parses a 20 MB csv file in less than 3 seconds on my machine).

```
Public Function getDataFromFile(parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String, Optional parExcludeCharacter As String = "") As Variant
'parFileName is supposed to be a delimited file (csv...)'
'Returns an empty array if file is empty or can't be opened
'number of columns based on the line with the largest number of columns, not on the first line'
'parExcludeCharacter: sometimes csv files have quotes around strings: "XXX" - if parExcludeCharacter = """" then quotes are removed'

  Dim locLinesList() As Variant
  Dim locData As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim locNumRows As Long
  Dim locNumCols As Long
  Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
  Dim ts As TextStream
  Const REDIM_STEP = 10000

  On Error GoTo error_open_file
  Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
  On Error GoTo unhandled_error

  'Counts the number of lines and finds the largest number of columns'
  ReDim locLinesList(1 To 1) As Variant
  i = 0
  Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    If i Mod REDIM_STEP = 0 Then
      ReDim Preserve locLinesList(1 To UBound(locLinesList, 1) + REDIM_STEP) As Variant
    End If
    locLinesList(i + 1) = Split(ts.ReadLine, parDelimiter)
    j = UBound(locLinesList(i + 1), 1) 'number of columns'
    If locNumCols < j Then locNumCols = j
    i = i + 1
  Loop

  ts.Close

  locNumRows = i

  If locNumRows = 0 Then Exit Function 'Empty file'

  ReDim locData(1 To locNumRows, 1 To locNumCols + 1) As Variant

  'Copies the file into an array'
  If parExcludeCharacter <> "" Then

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        If Left(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          If Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Mid(locLinesList(i)(j), 2, Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 2)       'If locTempArray = "", Mid returns ""'
          Else
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Right(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
          End If
        ElseIf Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          locLinesList(i)(j) = Left(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
        End If
      Next j
    Next i

  Else

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
      Next j
    Next i

  End If

  getDataFromFile = locData

  Exit Function

error_open_file: 'returns empty variant'
unhandled_error: 'returns empty variant'

End Function
```

Comment: hi thanks but  have to use ADO, need to be able to run SQL queries on the file

Comment: Depending on the query it might be easy to just iterate on the returned array and check some conditions, but I understand that you want to do it using ADO in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you locked into reading the CSV with ADO?  I always seem to run into problems trying to read textfiles with ADO like you are experiencing.  I usually just give up on the ADO side and read the file directly with a text reader to get more control.

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    Dim path As String

    path = "C:\test.csv"

    ReadText path
End Sub

Public Sub ReadText(path As String)
'requires reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' scrrun.dll OR use late binding

    Const DELIM As String = ","
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim text As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim line As String
    Dim vals() As String

    Set text = fso.OpenTextFile(path, ForReading)

    Do While Not text.AtEndOfStream

        line = text.ReadLine

        vals = Split(line, DELIM)

        'do something with the values
    Loop

    text.Close
End Sub
```